# Functional dependency F = {AB->CD , A->B} or A->C

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I have R(A,B,C,D) and functional dependencies AB->CD and A->B I want to know or A->C is correct?

I try found F closure by amstrong axioms:

```
AB->C (decomposition from AB->CD)
AB->D (decomposition from AB->CD)
AB->AB (reflexivity) 
AB->A (decomposition from AB->AB)
AB->B (decomposition from AB->AB)
A->A
B->B
AB->ABCD (Union) <- candidate key
```

I feel it is not all what I missing? Also I feel that A->C is correct because AB->C but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different ways to see if `A → C` can be derived by `AB → CD` and `A → B`: either you can try to calculate the closure of the attribute `A`, with the algorithm used to compute the closure of a set of attributes, and see if it contains `C` (easy way), or you can derive a proof of it by applying the Armstrong axioms (more difficult way).

Let’s first do it the easy way:

```
A+ = A     (starting point)
A+ = AB    (by using A → B)
A+ = ABCD  (by using AB → CD)
```

So, since `A+` contains `C`, we have shown that `A → C` belongs to `F+`, which is equivalent to say that `A → C` is implied by `AB → CD` and `A → B`.

Now let’s try the second way:

```
1. A → B    (given)
2. AB → CD  (given)
3. A → AB   (by 1. for enrichment, adding A both to left and right side of the dependency)
4. A → CD   (by 3. and 2. for transitivity)
5. A → C    (by 4. for decomposition)
```

What you will probably *do not want to do*, on the other hand, is to compute the closure of `F`, since this would be quite a lengthy and tedious task... (it is an exponential task!).

Answer (score 0):

AB->CD (given) 
thus, 
AB->C, and 
AB->D 
(by decomposition) 
A->B (given) 
So, A->AB, by augmentation 
thus, by transitivity, A->C & A->D!